# I cannot find 'Passwords and Forms' in my Chrome settings

Tags: google-chrome

I hope someone can help me. I'm getting mad. I'd like to manage my autofill settings.
I cannot find in Settings 'Passwords and Forms'.

I go to setting>Advanced Settings

But there is no 'Passwords and Forms'

I thank you in advance for help

Comment: Please edit your question and include which version of a chrome you are using

Comment: The first box in `Settings` (labelled `People`) has the line `Passwords`: click on this to show the settings you require.

Comment: @AFH What happened to editing autofill for forms? Nowhere to be found anymore

Comment: @Moab Same section as Passwords.  There's a search box at the top of the settings page, if you type in "form" it will filter and show passwords, payment methods, addresses, etc.

Comment: @Moab - Under `Passwords` you can edit sign-in details: other saved forms will appear under `Payment methods` or `Addresses and more`. I don't have any entries in the latter two categories (I normally use Firefox and its forks), so I can't verify that the entries are editable, but I have to assume that they are, as with `Passwords`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I'm grateful to all of you, I solved my problems and I found  how to manage auto fill forms.